# Difference between running ./pythonscript and python pythonscript.py

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script fetchcreative.py  which typically fetches some data from db . The script has execute permission . When i run the script using

```
./fetchcreative.py rtb:3778:4019617065
```

it fails with ImportError: No module named psycopg2.
But when i run using

```
python fetchcreative.py rtb:3778:4019617065
```

it works fine. Just want to understand , what is going on here ? Please point to corresponding reference where i can learn more about it .

Comment: What is the first line in `fetchcreative.py`?

Comment: are you using windows or Linux?

Comment: With a command line of `./fetchcreative.py`  (forward slash) I have assumed a unix derivative.

Comment: yeah, ok `./script.py` doesn't work on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./fetchcreative.py` will use the shebang (`#!`) magic at the beginning of the file to determine which python to run.

Usually it is best to have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the beginning of a `script.py` to get `python` from the environment (i.e. from $PATH) which should match (though aliases and other actions could make it different):

```
$ python script.py
```

However, if the `#!` is hard-coded to a specific `python` it may not match `python` on the command line.

Comment: I had  #!/usr/bin/python  at the beginning of the file  and it was not working , changing it to #!/usr/bin/env python worked , but i can python inside /usr/bin . What is the explanation for this ?

Comment: You haven't installed `psycopg2` in the system python, if you type `which python` it will show which python you have install `psycopg2` into.